# Jsoup forum Scraping

Tags: html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am scraping an online forum using Jsoup. Was wondering how should i go about scraping the main post without other's commenter's quote.

**What i managed to scrape:** carey wrote: Yup, CC usually got discounts, especially for petrol and makan... The black DBS debit card when used at petrol kiosk can get discount? I always pay cash because no cc.

**What i want:** The black DBS debit card when used at petrol kiosk can get discount? I always pay cash because no cc.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="post_message_63989045">
  <div class="quote"> 
    <span class="byline"> <a href="/eat-drink-man-woman-16/life-without-credit-cards-3601620-post63982949.html#post63982949" rel="nofollow"><img class="inlineimg" src="http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/img/forums/hwz/buttons/viewpost.gif" border="0" alt="View Post" /></a> <strong>carey</strong> wrote: </span> 
     <blockquote cite="showthread.php?p=63982949#post63982949">
        Yup, CC usually got discounts, especially for petrol and makan...
        <br /> 
        <br /> So those without a CC are being penalized 
        <img src="http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/img/forums/hwz/smilies/eek.gif" border="0" alt="" title="EEK!" class="inlineimg" /> 
     </blockquote> 
  </div>The black DBS debit card when used at petrol kiosk can get discount ?
  <br /> 
  <br /> I always pay cash because no cc . 
  <img src="http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/img/forums/hwz/smilies/frown.gif" border="0" alt="" title="Frown" class="inlineimg" />
</div>
```

Comment: in case you know the id ,try this `Element post_message= doc.getElementById("post_message_63989045").text();`

Comment: yup. this will yield all the text... I need a way to exclude the text in "class = quote"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comments.ownText()

Gets text that is owned by element. does not combine text with all children

Answer (score 1):

You could simply filter out `<div>`s that have a class of "quote", if whatever you use for scraping parses HTML tags

Comment: do i use this method: 

public Elements removeClass(String className)

Comment: which method can i use to filter this <div> that have a class of "quote"

Comment: I've never used Jsoup before so I'm not really sure

Answer (score 0):

If you can use XPaths, you can just query all text nodes that are direct childs:

```
//div[@id="post_message_63989045"]/text()
```

The quote will be ignored, since its text is a child of the quote-div. (probably as well as any code tags someone posts)